# Customizing Laravel's Authentiation System (Auth) to modify fields

Tags: laravel, authentication

everyone.
I'm currently new to the Laravel world, and recently began learning larval 5.  What I am currently trying to do is remove the field name from the users table and add a first name, last name, and a username field.

When I add these things to the default create_user migration file, it creates everything perfectly.  However, when I try to register, the remember token field in the database gets set to null, instead of the hash code or encryption value that the auth system normally places in this field.

I have updated just about everything I can find, such as a User model to include these three fields in the $fillable array, and I updated the validator and create methods in the AuthController to reflect the changes.

Does anyone know how to do this? or can someone point me to a better authentication system that is open source (and free of charge) that has better documentation.

I'm sure that Im not the only person that has tried to do this....

Oh, and one more thing.  I have been trying to locate the file that contains the logic for inserting the data into the users table for the Auth system and I don't seem too find it.  Does anyone know where this is at?

Back to the original topic.  It seems to me, that in altering the users table, the validator, and the create method on the AuthController, I have seemed to have overwritten the default value that the system normally places in this remember_token field.  I just need to know how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You know what guy?  Im am so sorry about this question.  It seems that Laravel updates this field after the user logs out.  apparently I didn't do that after I logged in.  So it doesn't fill in until after the user logs out.

Thanks guys.